# SQL - LAG equivalent using OVER clause to retrieve previous value and store in current row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a tables of dates where I need to store the previous row's `val` column in the current row. However, I cannot use `LAG` clause because there are dates that are missing and pulling the previous value and storing it in the current row should only happen if the immediate date previous exists. Thus I must (I think) use an `OVER()` and `RANGE` clause

For example, imagine the following table:

```
date      | val
-----------------
12/1/2020 | 1
12/2/2020 | 2
12/4/2020 | 3
12/5/2020 | 4
```

I'd like to be able to add an additional column with the value from the day before, and if the previous day doesn't exist, then store a 0

```
date      | val | prev_val
--------------------------
12/1/2020 | 1.  | 0
12/2/2020 | 2.  | 1
12/4/2020 | 3.  | 0 <--- notice how 12/3/2020 doesn't exist? that's why we store a 0
12/5/2020 | 4.  | 3
```

To populate `prev_val`, I figured I could do something like the following in my `SELECT` statement:

`SUM(val) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND NOT CURRENT ROW) as prev_val`

Obviously `NOT` does not exist, but that's the concept I'd have to go for right? I don't know the correct syntax to use to just get the single previous value and I cannot use `ROW` as that would not account for missing dates. What am I missing? I'm using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `LAG` along with a `CASE` expression which conditionally renders either the previous value of the immediately preceding day, or zero in the event that this day does not exist:

```sql
SELECT
    date,
    val,
    CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date)
         THEN LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY date)
         ELSE 0 END AS prev_val
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `lag()` for this.  You can use a window frame:

```
select t.*,
       (val -
        max(val) over (order by unix(date)
                       range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                      )
       ) as diff
from t;
```

This returns `NULL` if the value doesn't exist.  You can use `coalesce()` to handle that:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce( (val -
                  max(val) over (order by unix(date)
                                 range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                                )
                 ), 0
               ) as diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below less verbose option

```
select *,
  if(date - 1 = lag(date) over prev_rows, lag(val) over prev_rows, 0) prev_val 
from `project.dataset.table` 
window prev_rows as (order by date)
```

If applied to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select date '2020-12-01' date, 1 val union all
  select '2020-12-02', 2 union all
  select '2020-12-04', 3 union all
  select '2020-12-05', 4 
)
```

output is

[image]